# c++, method to display content in hash table.Using double linked list

Tags: c++, class, hash, linked-list

I am doing a hash table using double linked list.Since the code is long I am just posting the method I have problems with.

In my header file with my linked list class I have this method that would display the content of each node in my linked list.

```
void display()
{
    for (node * p = head; p != NULL; p = p->next)
    {
        cout << p->data << endl;
    }
    cout << endl;
}
```

Then I have my .cpp file where I have my class hashTable but I am not sure how to display the content of each list by using the method in my header file with the hash table. In my case my table has a size of 10. This is what I tried:

```
void showTable()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        cout << table[hash(i)].display() << " ";
}
```

The error I get is *no operator"<<"matches this operands*    and also
 *binary'<<':no operator found which takes a right hand operand of type 'void' (or there is no acceptable conversion)*

For reference this is my function hash

```
int hash(int x)
{
    return x % (size);              
}
```

Comment: You need to decide if `display` does the output or returns a string that you can print outside of it. You can't print the return value from a function that returns nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this to work, the display function must return a string or int.
Your display function returns void. That means your line of code is equivalent to:

```
cout << void << " ";
```

of course that makes no sense, as cout can only print strings and numbers.
I don't know all your code, but since display() already prints that node try replacing that line with:

```
table[hash(i)].display();
```

Comment: Thank you so much I feel embarrassed for not realizing that, thank you again